# Firebug - spotting error before page post

Tags: jquery, debugging, post, firebug

OK this is starting to drive me crazy!

I am trying to do some debugging with firebug, except I keep missing the error.

I have set break on all errors. Except that I think some jQuery code causes the page to post really quickly after the error-so I can't see it.

So my question is - how do I stop firefox/firebug from posting before I can read this error?

Comment: How about commenting out the jQuery code doing the post.

Comment: It doesn't add up. If you have break on error and the error happen before the post, there is no way any script is going to execute when there's an error. Either you're not having the error or there's something else going on.

Comment: error was caused somewhere in the jQuery code causing the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your firebug's console menu has a button called `persist`. This button keeps console messages even after your page has changed.

This is precisely the kind of scenario it was created for.